# How to merge RDD array

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a RDD array: `Array[RDD[(String, Double)]]`, how to merge those RDDs into `RDD[String, Array[Double]]`. For example:

```
RDD Array: [[('x', 1), ('y', 2)], [('x', 3), ('y', 4)],...] =>
RDD: [('x', [1, 3,...]), ('y', [2, 4, ...])]
```

Any help appreciated! Thanks

Comment: how did you get Array of RDD? I guess it should be RDD of Array, please confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You should merge the array of RDDS into one RDD (line 1)
2. Group them by the String value (line 2)
3. I see that the expected output is sorted, if it is required you can sort the values (line 3)

`val mergeIntoOne: RDD[(String, Double)] = array.fold(sparkSession.sparkContext.emptyRDD[(String, Double)])(_ ++ _)
  val groupByKeys: RDD[(String, Iterable[Double])] = mergeIntoOne.groupByKey()
  val sortedValues = groupByKeys.mapValues(_.toList.sorted)`

Comment: Thanks! After grouped(line 2), will order of elements in `groupByKeys` array be same with original array order? Or shuffled during fold?

Comment: I guess sorting is the only way to be sure. The order may differ because od data being repartitioned by Spark

Answer (score 0):

Assume you don't have duplicated keys in each RDD, then you could try foldLeft on the `Array[RDD]` with `fullOuterJoin` on all the rdds:

```
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("x", 1.0), ("y", 2.0)))
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("x", 3.0), ("y", 4.0)))
val rdd3 = sc.parallelize(Seq(("x", 5.0), ("y", 6.0)))

val rdds = Array(rdd1, rdd2, rdd3)

val startRdd = sc.parallelize(Seq[(String, Seq[Option[Double]])]())

(rdds.foldLeft(startRdd)(
    (rdd1, rdd2) => rdd1.fullOuterJoin(rdd2).mapValues(
        p => p._1.getOrElse(Seq[Option[Double]]()) :+ p._2
    )
 ).mapValues(_.collect{ case Some(x) => x }).collect)
// res15: Array[(String, Seq[Double])] = Array((x,List(1.0, 3.0, 5.0)), (y,List(2.0, 4.0, 6.0)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It is true nested RDD is not supported. Now the question actually is : Array[RDD(String, Double)], how to merge the RDD array into RDD(String, Array[Double]) ?

Comment: Can you update your question with the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score -2):

it depends on where you want to use it but you can use a for loop and union the arrays

```
scala> var a = Array(("a1",1.1))
a: Array[(String, Double)] = Array((a1,1.1))

scala> var b = Array(("a2",1.2))
b: Array[(String, Double)] = Array((a2,1.2))

scala>  for (i <- 0 to b.length) {
 |  a = a:+b(i)}

scala> a
res2: Array[(String, Double)] = Array((a1,1.1), (a2,1.2))
```

Comment: I do not see any RDDs here. Did you notice he had asked a question about Apache Spark?