# combine elements into arrays in rdd

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

how can I convert an `RDD[(Int,Int)]` to an `RDD[Array[(Int,Int)]]` where I combine elements with their key.

Lets say

> (0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(0,1)

and I want it to be an Array arr1 = ((0,0),(1,0)) and an arr2 ((1,1),(0,1))
So the resulted rdd will have arr1,arr2 as arrays.

Comment: `rdd.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.toArray)` should get you pretty close.

Comment: thank you it works. if you make it an answer I will choose it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge RDD array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45497362/how-to-merge-rdd-array)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're basically trying to do is group an `RDD[TupleN]` by the `i`th element. You can use

```
rdd.groupBy(_._1)
```

to create a

```
Map[T, RDD[TupleN]]
```

where the key will be the `i`th element (i.e., 0 or 1 in your example).

Then you can map the values of this map to an array with `mapValues(_.toArray)`

Comment: and if I want to combine successive keys to an array? so keys 0,1 would be in one array and 2,3 in another?